# Question's body rendering in Android's webview

Tags: support, api

I've developed an app that get questions from Stack using REST APIs and shows them in a WebView. My problem now is that the body often contains placeholders that must be "replaced" with the real information, for example formula's chars from the Math site. By looking at the HTML source for Stack's pages I suppose that it's up to javascript to do that, and I'm trying to understand how can I do the same in an App. Is there an official list of replacing to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you query the [site list](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites), the `markdown_extensions` property for each site will contain the list of enabled post-processing extensions, if applicable.

Some possible extensions are:

- [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/)
- [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)
- [Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

I believe [jTab](http://jtab.tardate.com/) is also used on the [Music site](http://music.stackexchange.com), and there's a [Chess extension](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site/175#175) on the [Chess site](https://chess.stackexchange.com/), but these additions aren't listed in the `markdown_extensions` property.